# "convert" shared libraries between different arm toolchains

Tags: arm, shared-libraries, toolchain

I have a couple of shared libraries as .so created using the toolchain arm-bcrm-linux-gnueabi(A), and another device that uses the toolchain arm-linux-android-eabi(B), is there a way to "convert" the .so from toolchain A to toolchain B ? I don't have access to the source code

Answer (score 0):

One is using the glibc and the other is using [bionic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bionic_(software)). You can not mix and match them. However, you can have both shared libraries systems; all shared libraries in a final binary must link to the base 'c' library. Theoretically you could do the opposite of [hybris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybris_(software)); ie, introduce a translation library. There is no simple answer as the software doesn't exist. This is why some people frown on bionic and Google for creating it, because it creates this fragmentation.  Of course the counter argument is bionic is *better* than glibc, which is true from some perspectives/metrics.